# add icon to right most corner of PrimeNg TabView Header

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, primeng

I need to place an icon on the right most corner of a PrimeNG [TabView](https://primeng.org/tabview)

i looking for something like this

[image]

for demonstration purposes i opened the stackblitz in the docs and hardcoded the css but it will not be resposive when screen size changes

```html
    <p-tabView>
        <p-tabPanel header="Header I">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum
            </p>
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Header II">
            <p>
                Sed ut perspiciatis
            </p>
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Header III">
            <p>
                At vero eos et
            </p>
        </p-tabPanel>
        <i class="pi pi-sort-alt icon-position"></i>
    </p-tabView>
```

```css
.icon-position {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30rem;
  top: 3rem;
}
```

Comment: @JasperdeVries sorry i thought primefaces and primeng are related

Comment: @JasperdeVries https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/tabView.xhtml?jfwid=ae9f0 i was wondering if something similar can be done. There is a text on the right side in first and second examples

Comment: Can you make separate designs that would work for separate screen sizes? If so, then your problem can be resolved with media queries.

Comment: the tabView is from a component library so it is responsive. since i hardcoded the position of icon that is the issue. im not sure how many media queries i need to write

Comment: Binga, you can hard-code the position for several screen sizes and apply responsivity via media queries. I'm not speaking about the other rules that are already responsive and work well, but about your rules that are not yet responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Inject renderer2 in your constructor.

```
constructor(private _renderer2:Renderer2){}
```

2 - Add template reference on `p-tabView` like `#tabView` and read with `@ViewChild`

```
<p-tabView #tabView>
```

```
@ViewChild('tabView') tabView:TabView;
```

3 - Implments `AfterViewInIt`

4 - Create function which create icon using renderer and listen to the click event of the icon:

```
  createSortIcon(){
    const icon = this._renderer2.createElement('i');
    this._renderer2.addClass(icon,'pi')
    this._renderer2.addClass(icon,'pi-sort-alt');
    this._renderer2.setStyle(icon,'position','absolute');
    this._renderer2.setStyle(icon,'cursor','pointer');
    this._renderer2.setStyle(icon,'right','0')
    const nav_header = (this.tabView.content.nativeElement as HTMLElement).firstChild;
    this._renderer2.appendChild(nav_header,icon);
    this._renderer2.listen(icon,'click',() =>{
      this.myFunc() // put here your function
    })
  }
```

5- Call `createSortIcon()` inside the `ngAfterViewInIt()`

Comment: hi will i be able to add click listeners to this now since i didnt have to write the <i> in html

Comment: https://codeshare.io/EBz74P        this what i did but canot add a click listener

Comment: I'll edit my answer to add a clickable icon

Comment: https://codeshare.io/ZJ4Py7  i tried these and looks like it working. i'll wait a couple more days if there are other suggestions and accept if not

Answer (score 2):

It's not ideal but you can set display flex to card container and add the icon outside of the panel. [see stackblitz working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/gd7tna?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftab-view-basic-demo.html)

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="tabs">
    <p-tabView>
      <p-tabPanel header="Header I">
        <p> Tab 1 </p>
      </p-tabPanel>
      <p-tabPanel header="Header II">
        <p> Tab 2 </p>
      </p-tabPanel>
      <p-tabPanel header="Header III">
        <p> Tab 3</p>
      </p-tabPanel>
    </p-tabView>
  </div>

  <div class="sort">
    <i class="pi pi-sort-alt" (click)="onSortClick()"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Overwrite `.p-tabview-panels` class with `z-index` and `width` to be displayed over the sort element allocated content and add a `border-bottom` to sort icon, to make it like it's part of the tab element

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .p-tabview-panels {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    width: 110%;
  }
}

.card {
  display: inline-flex;

  .tabs {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .sort {
    margin-left: 8px;
    padding: 1.1rem;
    position: relative;

    &::after {
      content: '';
      border-bottom: 2px solid #dee2e6;
      display: block;
      margin-top: 1.1rem;
      margin-left: -24px;
      width: 52px;
    }
  }
}
```

You can of course adjust the css values to fit your context

Answer (score 2):

You can use a full prime solution, mixing tabview template and wrapping ina prime grid flex both the tabview and the icon:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="col-11">
      <p-tabView styleClass="tabview-custom">
        <p-tabPanel>
          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <span>Header I</span>
          </ng-template>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Header II">
          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <span>Header II</span>
          </ng-template>
          <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error</p>
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Header III">
          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <span>Header III</span>
          </ng-template>
          <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio</p>
        </p-tabPanel>
      </p-tabView>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <i class="pi pi-sort-alt"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [working fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kgu8ep?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftab-view-template-demo.html)

Answer (score 1):

wrap the code in `<span>` and add **class** in `<p-tabView class="example-class">`.

```
<p-tabView class="example-class">
  <span>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header I">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header II">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis</p>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header III">
      <p>At vero eos et</p>
    </p-tabPanel>
  </span>
  <span>
    <i class="pi pi-sort-alt"></i>
  </span>
</p-tabView>
```

```css
.example-class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: doesnt work unfortunatley

Comment: please share your live code.

Comment: hi if you go to https://primeng.org/tabview it shows a Basic example. you can open it in stackblitz they have give a button to open in stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more panel:

```
<p-tabPanel header="" tabindex="-1">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <i class="pi pi-sort-alt" (click)="$event.preventDefault();$event.stopPropagation();yourSortMethod();"></i>
  </ng-template>
</p-tabPanel>
```

and add styles:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-tabview-nav:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  
  a {
    padding: 0;

    i {
      padding: 1.25rem;
    }

    &:hover {
      border-color: #dee2e6;
    }
  }
}
```